# A property similar to the convexity, but actually different?

Tags: calculus, geometry, convex-analysis

If we know there exists a point $x_0$, such that $f(x_0)$ lies below the tangent line at $0$ of $f(x)$, which means below the line $y=f(0)+f'(0)x$.

My question is how to prove this violate $f(0)\le \lambda_1f(x_1)+(1-\lambda_1)f(x_2)$ for which $\lambda_1 x_1+(1-\lambda_1)x_2=0$?

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks so much!

I still cannot solve the problem even with the hint. Can someone explain it for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider $$\frac{f(\lambda x_0) - f(0)}{\lambda x_0 - 0}$$ for $0 < \lambda < 1$.

Comment: @ Hi, Daniel. I found $\frac{f(\lambda x_0-f(0))}{\lambda x_0-0} \le f'(0)$ for some $\lambda$ by observing the graph. But I don't know what to do next. Could you give me more hints? Thanks!

Comment: "Below the tangent line" means _strictly below the tangent line_. And note the difference between $x_0 > 0$ and $x_0 < 0$.